# React Native Expo Camera: No Shutter Sound on Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am using the expo camera to build a react native app, based on the example found here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/.

I've noticed that there is no capture sound on Android. I do not have this problem on iPhone. So far I haven't found a way to configure the shutter sound.

Is this a known issue or is there a fix out there?

Comment: did you found any sollution?